# #VALUE using indirect in different workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'[Workbook]Worksheet'!" & "A" & SUM(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1, '[Workbook]Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$463),0),1)):$A$463,MATCH(1,COUNTIF($B$509,INDIRECT("'[Workbook]Worksheet'!K" & SUM(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1, '[Workbook]Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$463),0),1)):$K$463),0),),"")
```

In the original workbook (without the workbook redirect) the formula works perfectly fine, but when I try to move it to a different workbook the evaluate formula shows that the Indirect formula gives me a full path string of the workbook with the cell reference, seemingly with no issues, but the next step results in a #VALUE error. Why doesn't Excel recognize '[Workbook]Worksheet'!A1:A463 when created through INDIRECT if it would without and how to fix it?

Comment: IS the other workbook closed? Indirect doesn't work with closed workbooks,

Comment: Not when I was testing it, neither now, though that does complicate the situation in the long run. If at least this issue would get resolved I'd be happy and I could work on a different workaround

Comment: If both are open then the issue is with your formula syntax. Without knowing what elements of the formula resolve to it would be impossible to give the exact answer.

Comment: I suspect as much, however the formula looks just like the one pasted in the OG post, except "Workbook" and "Worksheet" have actual names. I made sure not to make a mistake with them by copying their paths from a different, working formula. Without pasting the formula into different workbook, it works perfectly fine, but when I try to use it in a different workbook it breaks.